# when I use CGAL LSCM，there are some overlaps

Tags: mesh, cgal, parameterization

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4cueR.png)

when I use CGAL LSCM，I find there are some overlaps.
there are some descriptions in CGAL doc.
But I still want to use CGAL LSCM  to achieve Mesh Parameterization，so what can I do to solve the problem.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a92DM.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The LSCM parameterization is not guaranteed to create a 1-to-1 mapping, so folds can indeed happen.

You can attempt to improve the parameterization by using the class [MVC_post_processor_3](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Surface_mesh_parameterization/classCGAL_1_1Surface__mesh__parameterization_1_1MVC__post__processor__3.html), which uses mean value coordinates to try and recover a 1-to-1 parameterization.